# GraphQL and data transform

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I have limited capabilities on my client, and need to send unstructured data to GraphQL.

I'll have a query like this:

```
mutation createDroid {
  payload: "R2-D2,Astromech,NEWHOPE\,EMPIRE\,JEDI"
}
```

And want to turn it into schema like this:

```
type Droid {
  name: String!
  function: String!
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
}
```

Would this be the right way to define the `Mutator`

```
type Mutation {
  createDroid(string payload): Droid
}
```

All I would have to do is make sure the resolver returns an Object with `name` `function` and `appearsIn` properties to invoke the schema validation?

Something makes me think I would need to build a new query and call 
`graphql(schema, query, resolvers)` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you only need to make sure the resolver returns a correct Object ;)

On a side note, correct query and mutation definition syntax:

```
mutation CreationOfTheDroid {
  createDroid(payload: "R2-D2,Astromech,NEWHOPE\,EMPIRE\,JEDI") {
    // ...
  }
}

type Mutation {
  createDroid(payload: String!): Droid!
}
```